# jquery post load index page in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

Jquery -> View -> v_addEmployee::

```
function get_subdepartment() {
var dep_selected = $('select[name=txtDept]').val();
$.ajax({
    data: {
        dept: dep_selected,
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addEmployee/getSubDept',
    success: function(data){ 
        console.log(data);
        alert(dep_selected);
        $('.subDept').html(data);
    }
})
```

}

View -> v_addEmployee:

```
                    $rs_dept = $this->m_addVacancy->getDepartment();
                $deptOption['-'] = 'Select Department';
                if ($rs_dept){
                    foreach($rs_dept as $row_dept){
                        $deptOption[$row_dept->dept] = $row_dept->dept;
                    }
                }
            //echo form_dropdown($name = 'txtDept',$Options = $department, array($this->input->post('txtDept')) ,'class="txt2" style="width: 96% " onChange="get_subdepartment1();"');
            echo form_dropdown('txtDept',$deptOption, array($this->input->post('txtDept')),'class="txt2" style="width: 96% " onChange="get_subdepartment();" onSelect="get_subdepartment();"');
```

Controller:
In addEmployee/getSubDept exist or not it addEmployee/index

```
        function index(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('v_addEmployee');
    }


function getSubDept(){ echo $this->input->post(dept); }
```

In .subDept it is displaying addEmployee/index page. Pls help

Comment: post your codes in `getSubDept()` functions too

Comment: 'addEmployee/getSubDept' is a directory or rewritten URL ?

Comment: addEmployee is controller name & getSubDept is function name of addEmployee

Comment: does your PHP see it the same way?

Comment: Latest actual code after trying all stuff. Pleas help guys

Comment: I'm not familiar with `CodeIgniter` but AFAIK `jQuery.ajax()` can just accept an string address as URL. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Its done started automatically where logout & relogin done

Answer (score 0):

that might be routing problem, try changing:

```
url: 'addEmployee/getSubDept',
```

to

```
url: '/addEmployee/getSubDept',
```

or

```
url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>addEmployee/getSubDept',
```

Check in consoleto see if your ajax post is getting redirected.